# Redis: Database Size to Memory Ratio (running out of ram in Windows)

Tags: windows, memory, redis

I'm running a recent version of Redis on Windows 7, and have a redis db that's 13GB, so I upgraded my comptuers ram to 24GB, but apparently that's not enough, and redis apparently is not designed to use virtual memory*.

There's prob no way to predict the amount of ram I will need (correct me if I'm wrong), so what's my best option here? I am just trying to analyze its database for now.

- "In the past the Redis developers experimented with Virtual Memory and other systems in order to allow larger than RAM datasets, but after all we are very happy if we can do one thing well: data served from memory, disk used for storage. So for now there are no plans to create an on disk backend for Redis. Most of what Redis is, after all, is a direct result of its current design."

Answer (score 2):

You could use [redis-rdb-tool](https://github.com/sripathikrishnan/redis-rdb-tools) on your dump file, and generate a memory report.

You can also use the same package to extract the data from the Redis dump file in order to feed another storage engine, more adapted to the size of your data.